# how to get textview text

Tags: java, android, listview, textview

In my android app, I have a activity that contain a listview. And within the each row of the listview, i have another listview let called it lv. Inside this lv, it contain some textview. My question is how can i get the text from the listview (A)?

I know that if there is only one listview and in order to get the text of each row when i click on a button, i can use the following code

```
textview.getText().toString();
```

However, when i try with this code to get the text in lv, it always give me the last value (n row) in lv. I am not able to get the text of 1st row to n-1 row of lv.

**UPDATE:** 
The follow are the code where i want to get the text, the ordered[] is passed from a custom adapter to another custom adapter (which is the following code)

```
public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null,true);

    txt1 = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txt2 = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    txt3 = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    txt4 = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    txt5 = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    txt6 = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView6);




    txtoid = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    final Button btnGet = (Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.btnGet);


    tmp = position;
    String tmp2 = String.valueOf(ordered[position]);
    txtoid.setText(tmp2);

    btnGet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(btnconfirm.getText().toString().equals("Get")){
                String tmp1 = txtq.getText().toString();
                System.out.println("tmp1: "+tmp1); 




            }

        }
    });
....
```

Anyone help will be nice!

Thanks

Comment: Put your code where you are trying to get the text.

Comment: @AndroidKiller i have update the code, i used the custom adapter for each list view, the code above is for the lv

Comment: where you have initialize txtq in your code ?

Comment: `txt1`,`txt2`, etc etc belong to lv?

Comment: @SamirBhatt i initialize all at the start before onCreate

Comment: @Droidekas yes it belong to lv

Answer (score 0):

```
 rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View rootView) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       TextView  myText = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
       Log.d("","myText:" + myText.getText()); //you can get each row values.

    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply, i click on the button to get each row textview value and how you get the text isn't it same as my code?